# How can I animate a QML three way toggle

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to make a three-way-toggle in qml where the red rectangle  animates/slides to the clicked position. The toggle contains only images and no text:

[image]

MyToggle.qml

```
Rectangle {
        color: "gray"
        width: 400
        height: 50
        Row {
            id: rowId
            MyRadioButton {
                id: button1
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("clicked on button1")
                    animationId.restart()
                }
            }
            MyRadioButton {
                id: button2
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("clicked on button2")
                }
            }
            MyRadioButton {
                id: button3
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("clicked on button3")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    PropertyAnimation {
        id: animationId
        target: button3
        property: "x"
        duration: 1000
        to: 0
        easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
    }
}
```

MyRadioButton.qml

```
RadioButton {
   id: button1
   width: 90
   height: 100
   Image {
    source: "qrc:/image.png"
    sourceSize.width: 50
    sourceSize.height: 50
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
}
indicator: Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 50
    color: "red"
    opacity: 0.8
    visible: button1.checked
  }
}
```

The PropertyAnimation is wrong because it moves the whole button and not just the indicator. If I move the animation into MyRadioButton, I won't know how far to move "x".
Does anybody have some ideas how to implement this?

Comment: what is the desired behavior?

Comment: I'd like the red rectangle to slide to where I clicked.

Comment: The red rectangle shouldn't be a child of an individual radio button then, because you only want a single red rectangle that moves across all 3 buttons. I recommend using a ListView and setting the `highlight` object to be your red Rectangle. I'll see if I can whip up a quick example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your indicator Rectangle floating with a `Behavior` defined on `x`.

Thanks, @Greko for the improved indicator `target` binding. I tried both but elected to go with `ButtonGroup` as it seemed more qml.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Frame {
        background: Rectangle { color: "gray" }
        padding: 0
        Row {
            id: rowId
            MyRadioButton {
                id: button1
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("clicked on button1")
                    animationId.restart()
                }
            }
            MyRadioButton {
                id: button2
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("clicked on button2")
                }
            }
            MyRadioButton {
                id: button3
                onClicked: {
                    console.log("clicked on button3")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ButtonGroup {
        id: buttonGroup
        buttons: rowId.children
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: indicator
        property Item target: buttonGroup.checkedButton
        x: target ? target.x : 0
        y: target ? target.y : 0
        width: target ? target.width : 0
        height: target ? target.height : 0
        color: "red"
        opacity: 0.5
        Behavior on x { NumberAnimation { duration: 300 }}
    }
}

// MyRadioButton.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
RadioButton {
    id: button1
    width: 90
    height: 50
    Image {
        source: "cross.svg"
        sourceSize.width: 50
        sourceSize.height: 50
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    }
    indicator: Item { }
}

// cross.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" d="M 8 8 24 24"/>
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" d="M 8 24 24 8"/>
</svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

The following edit describes how to limit the NumberAnimation to only when an onClick occurs:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Frame {
        background: Rectangle { color: "gray" }
        padding: 0
        Row {
            id: rowId
            MyRadioButton {
                id: button1
                onClicked: NumberAnimation {
                    target: indicator
                    property: "x"
                    to: button1.x
                }
            }
            MyRadioButton {
                id: button2
                onClicked: NumberAnimation {
                    target: indicator
                    property: "x"
                    to: button2.x
                }
            }
            MyRadioButton {
                id: button3
                onClicked: NumberAnimation {
                    target: indicator
                    property: "x"
                    to: button3.x
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ButtonGroup {
        id: buttonGroup
        buttons: rowId.children
    }
    Rectangle {
        id: indicator
        property Item target: buttonGroup.checkedButton
        x: 0
        y: target ? target.y : 0
        width: target ? target.width : 0
        height: target ? target.height : 0
        color: "red"
        opacity: target ? 0.5 : 0
    }
}

// MyRadioButton.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
RadioButton {
    id: button1
    width: 90
    height: 50
    Image {
        source: "cross.svg"
        sourceSize.width: 50
        sourceSize.height: 50
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    }
    indicator: Item { }
}

// cross.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" d="M 8 8 24 24"/>
<path stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" d="M 8 24 24 8"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: The indicator target binding could be changed to `Array.from(rowId.children).find(rb => rb.checked)` to not have to hardcode the button ids. Using a `ButtonGroup` would work to.
`ButtonGroup {id: buttonGroup; buttons: rowId.children }` and then `target: buttonGroup.checkedButton`

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to work using Behavior on x. The only problem was that it also animates when the visibility changes. Is there a way around that to only animate when the user actually clicks? Looks to me like I might have to use a property animation instead...

Comment: I don't fully understand, but, perhaps it is solvable with Behavior.enabled ?

Answer (score 1):

Using a ListView to contain the three buttons makes it easier because it already has a single highlight object that animates across the items. For simpler testing, I just used a regular Button instead of a RadioButton, but hopefully this should show you what needs to be done.

```
ListView {
    id: lv
    width: 300
    orientation: ListView.Horizontal
    model: 3
    delegate: Button {
        width: 100
        height: 40
        text: "X"
        
        onClicked: {
            lv.currentIndex = index
        }
    }
    highlight: Rectangle {
        color: "#7fff0000"
        z: 2
    }
}
```